# How to get authentication data from cookie

Tags: firefox, cookies

I created a gmail account a while ago . But I forgot my password . However , my firefox browser allows me to login because my login info is stored in cookie .

I want to be able to login to my account from other browsers .

Is there any way i could get that login information from the coockies in firefox

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cookies should never be used for storing any login credentials. That cookie probably contains some session information that is checked on server side.

**You can't extract your username and password from the cookie.**

If your only object is to use the cookie to login from different browsers, you can use one of many addons designed for Firefox or Chrome to transfer the cookie and use it to login.